# Laravel Jetstream - Is Sanctum required to protect the web routes?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-sanctum, laravel-jetstream

We're using the latest version of `Laravel` with `Laravel Jetstream` and want to implement a functionality to allow our admins to sign in on behalf of a regular user. This allows us to provide a better support if some users encounter problems with their accounts.

[This function](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authentication#authenticate-a-user-by-id) seems perfect to achieve the intended result:

```
Auth::loginUsingId(1);
```

Unfortunately I recieve the the following error message

```
Method Illuminate\Auth\RequestGuard::loginUsingId does not exist
```

After some time and thanks to the help of [Laravel Debugbar](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-debugbar) I figured out that the problem is caused by `Laravel Sanctum`. It does not include the above function and is set as `middleware` to protect the routes in the `app\routes\web.php` file.

It seems to work after changing the `middleware` from

```
Route::middleware(['auth:sanctum', 'verified'])
```

to

```
Route::middleware(['auth', 'verified'])
```

So long story short:
**Is there another solution to do this? Or better: is this even a valid solution? Can I just remove `Sanctum` from the web routes or is this requiered for some reason?** We want to still use `Sanctum` to authenticate our mobile applications our token based API.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sanctum provides a simple mechanism (compared to Passport) for authentication of your APIs and SPAs (served by an API).

If you're not developing a SPA you are not required to make use of the `auth:sanctum` middleware and can instead make use of the web `auth` middleware.

You can still and should make use of the sanctum middleware in your `routes/api.php` file.

Comment: Nice, that's what I was hoping for. Yes, we definetly will use Sanctum for the `routes/api.php`. Thank you.